# Probability of drawing either a heart, diamond or ace having removed some cards

Tags: probability

just a quick question;

Suppose that we take a standard pack of 52 playing cards and then remove the ace of clubs, the ace of hearts, the queen of hearts and the queen of diamonds. Suppose now that we pick a card from the remaining pack. What is the probability of picking either a heart or a diamond or an ace?

If I denote the suits by $H, D, S,$ and $C$ and the Aces by $A_i$ with the appropriate lettered subscript, I suppose the question is asking for

$$P(H \cup D \cup A_i).$$

What do I do here? The three events aren't all mutually exclusive (I can pick $D \cap A_D$, but not $H \cap A_H$). The $\cup$ is an associative operation so I can look at this as $P[H \cup (D \cup A_i)]$ and then I'll have some formula like

$$P[H \cup (D \cup A_i)] = P(H) + P(D \cup A_i).$$

Is this the correct approach to take? In which case, I'll have

$$P(H) + P(D \cup A_i) = P(H) + P(D) + P(A_i) - P(D \cap A_i).$$

This gives me

$$P(H) + P(D) + P(A_i) - P(D \cap A_i) = \frac{11}{48} + \frac{12}{48} + \frac{2}{48} - \frac{1}{96} = \frac{49}{96}.$$

Is there more to it than this?

Comment: What makes you think that the probability of picking the ace of diamonds is $\frac1{96}$? It is just $\frac1{48}$.

Comment: Duh. Thank you for your help. I thought of $P(D \cap A_i)$ as $\frac{12}{48} \times \frac{2}{48}$

Comment: $P(H\cup D\cup A)=P(H)+P(D)+P(A)-P(H\cap D)-P(H\cap A)-P(D\cap A)+P(H\cap D\cap A)$

Comment: This can just be worked out. Some of these terms will take value $0$. If you repaired the mistake I mentioned then it is okay.

Comment: I thought that $P(D \cap A_i) = P(D)P(A_i)$ which is where my confusion comes from.. surely $$P(D|A_i) = \frac{1}{48}$$

Comment: $P(D\cap A)=\frac1{48}$. I guess you mean to say that. Not $P(D|A_i)$.  Under the condition that you pick an ace the probability that it is a diamond is $\frac12$ here.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you did a little mistake, or I am just stupid.

$$P(H) = \frac{11}{48}\quad P(D) = \frac{12}{48}$$
$$P(A_i) = \frac{2}{48}\quad P(D \cap A_i) = \frac{1}{48}$$
Thus your probability would be:
$$\frac{11}{48} + \frac{12}{48}+\frac{2}{48}-\frac{1}{48}=\frac{24}{48}$$

Comment: You're not stupid, the mistake was my own. Thanks ;)

Comment: Not a problem my friend, have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

As with all probabilities, work out the size of the "successful events" space and divide it by the size of the "total events" space.  You have taken 4 from 52 cards, so the total space is 48 equally likely choices.

How many of those would quality as "successful"?  Well you have 11 hearts, 12 diamonds and the ace of spades which is 24.  Therefore the probability is 24/48 = 1/2.

Comment: You've read the question wrong, I've taken 4 from 52 cards :)